# Convert Long date to specific short date format

Tags: date, datepicker, long-integer, short

Convert Long date format to specific short date format.

I want to get the Date from Datepicker(Jcalander) , format to **dd-mm-yyyy** format and assign to String variable. I tried using codes shown below. But didnt get the date format i want.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) jCalendarCombo1.getDateFormat();
Date date = jCalendarCombo1.getDate();
System.out.println(date); // Prints Thu Mar 28 00:00:00 IST 2013


String s = simpleFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(s); // prints Thursday, March 28, 2013

System.out.println("Date SHORT format: "  + DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date));  // prints 3/28/13
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a *fixed*, non locale dependent format, you can just create it yourself;

```
SimpleDateFormat shortformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String s = shortformat.format(date);
System.out.println(s);                        // Prints 29-03-2013
```

Comment: Thnx for your quick response. it works now. I got the date in 29-03-2013 format. thnx again.